# Erro de consulta a uma URL JSON "getContentHandler, getContent"

Tags: java, json, http, gson

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento de um app que realiza consultas a diversos sites com retorno JSON e trato estas informações de diversas maneiras.

Para testar as URLs utilizo o código abaixo, funciona bem com um terço dos sites. Testo eles por este código e depois coleto as informações que preciso no app que estou desenvolvendo, só que muitos sites estão apresentando o erro que destacarei abaixo e não estou encontrando material na internet para resolver o problema.

Abaixo colocarei o código que funciona com diversos sites, porém deixarei nele um dos sites que mostra o erro. Se possível, além de indicarem o material, me mande o código corrigido que analisarei em seguida, só que não posso parar o APP agora para analisar primeiro, segue meu código para testes:

```
package Metodos;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Braziliex
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try {
              String sURL = "https://braziliex.com/api/v1/public/ticker/eth_brl";
                URL url = new URL(sURL);
                HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                request.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
                request.connect();
                JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); 
                JsonObject root = (JsonObject) jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
                System.out.println(root.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

No teste somente tento fazer a impressão no console, caso eu consiga, coloco o site dentro do meu APP e trato as informações conforme minha necessidade, mas este site está dando o seguinte erro:

java.net.UnknownServiceException: no content-type
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentHandler(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at Metodos.Braziliex.main(RetornaVanegandoLista.java:22)

Lembrando que o site está ativo e funcionando no browser normalmente, trazendo as informações da consulta. Já tentei diversas formas de pegar as informações e nunca saio deste erro, o que posso fazer?

Um exemplo de site que funciona bem com este código: https://api.bitcointrade.com.br/v2/public/BRLBTC/ticker

Comment: Possivelmente você não está enviando no Java todos os headers necessários. O browser os envia e por isso consegue receber a resposta corretamente. Comece tentando isto aqui: `request.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");`. Se não funcionar, sugiro clicar F12 no browser, fazer a requisição, observar os headers que são enviados e reproduzi-los em seu código.

Comment: Acho que estamos no caminho certo, erro 403 solucionado, porém temos outro agora...   java.net.UnknownServiceException: no content-type
 at java.net.URLConnection.getContentHandler(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContent(Unknown Source)
 at Metodos.RetornaVanegandoLista.main(RetornaVanegandoLista.java:22) ..... seria interessante eu atualizar a pergunta com o novo erro?

Comment: Adicionei o código após modificação e novo erro, obrigado desde já pela ajuda, acho que iremos conseguir resolver ^^... abraços.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, o erro agora estava no comando request.getContent, alterei para request.getInputStream() e consegui capturar o valor que eu queria, obrigado pelo inicio da solução StatelessDev...